# How can I refactor my library to include templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to add template functionality to my vector class, after already having used it without templates throughout my project.

The old version used hardcoded `float` to save the values for `x`, `y` and `z`. What I am trying to do now is to make the class also be able to use double through a template.

My class definition looks like this:

```
namespace alg {

template <class T=float> // <- note the default type specification
struct vector
{
    T x, y, z;
    vector() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    explicit vector(T f) : x(f), y(f), z(f) {}
    vector(T x, T y, T z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    // etc
};

}
```

I was hoping to now be able to compile my project without making changes to the code in it, by telling the template to use `float` per default if no template parameter is given.

However, I am still getting errors about missing template arguments...

```
#include "vector.hpp"

int main() {
    alg::vector a;
    return 0;
}
```

--

```
$ g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++0x test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:17: error: missing template arguments before ‘a’
test.cpp:4:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a’
```

How can I make this code work without changing `test.cpp`? Preferably without mangling the `struct` name and using `typedef`

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but have you considered a straightforward search-and-replace from `alg::vector` to `alg::vector<float>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to a class template without angle brackets is illegal, unfortunately.

The way the STL does this with `std::string` is like this, even though your request was "no mangling":

```
template <typename T> class basic_string { ... };
...
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

In your case, you would have to write `vector<>` everywhere, or rename your 
template:

```
template <class T>
struct basic_vector {
    ...
};

typedef basic_vector<float> vector;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the nice examples. I guess there is no other way around it then.

Comment: I think that top line of code should have been `template <typename T> class basic_string { ... };`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you have to write `alg::vector<>` even if you have a default typename.

Answer (score 0):

in all of my experience you can't. you need to change your `alg::vector` to `alg::vector<>` which is the syntax for the default argument. although  single find and replace should do this.